# Strange arrow function parameters behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

What the difference between these two code snippets?

```
const Article = ({article}) => {
    return ( 
        <article key={article.id}>
            <a href={article.link}>{article.title}</a>
            <p>{article.description}</p>
        </article>
    );
};
```

and this one:

```
const Article = (article) => {
    return ( 
        <article key={article.id}>
            <a href={article.link}>{article.title}</a>
            <p>{article.description}</p>
        </article>
    );
};
```

The only difference is curly brackets in arrow function parameters list... but it have different behavior... in first example `article` accessable as a plain object... but in the second one, article accessable like some kind of getter or something like that...

Comment: Has nothing to do with arrow functions, that's destructuring syntax in ES2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is using the destructuring syntax of es6.

Essentially `Article` is expecting an object. Which is then being destructured into new properties.

Your first item:

```
const Article = ({article}) => {
  return ( 
    <article key={article.id}>
      <a href={article.link}>{article.title}</a>
      <p>{article.description}</p>
    </article>
 );
};
```

Is equivalent to:

```
const Article = (props) => {
  const article = props.article;
  return ( 
    <article key={article.id}>
      <a href={article.link}>{article.title}</a>
      <p>{article.description}</p>
    </article>
 );
};
```

The mozilla developer network has a great article on both array/object destructuring forms: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Got It. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's an ES6 feature for destructuring arrays and objects.

http://es6-features.org/#ParameterContextMatching

Comment: Thanks! Now I see it... missed something... One more link about the issue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment